# Cleanup a path list in bash, removing all children paths (subdirectories)

Tags: bash

I have a file containing a list of paths like the following:

```
/some/path
/some/path/file
/some/path/subpath/file
/some/otherpath
/some/otherpath/file
```

As of today, I iterate of that list, check if the path exists, and if so, I delete the path / file.
This works, but isn't very optimized since once a directory is deleted, I can safely assume that all of it's children are deleted too.
I also happen to use that list in rsync as exclude list, which is quite cpu extensive because the list can be quite big.

I'd like to clean that list before using it, meaning that if `/some/path` exists, all children paths ie `/some/path/*` can be safely removed from the list.

The result list of the example above should look like

```
/some/path
/some/otherpath
```

The list is already sorted, meaning there won't be a case like

```
/some/path/file
/some/path
```

What's the fastest way to do so in GNU bash ?

Thanks.

[EDIT]

Source list is generated as follows:

rsync creates a list of files in paths, using grep and sed to 'clean' rsync output

```
    # rsync operation explanation
    # (command || :) = Return code 0 regardless of command return code
    # (grep -E \"^-|^d|^l\" || :) = Be sure line begins with '-' or 'd' or 'l' (rsync semantics for file, directory or symlink)
    # (sed -r 's/^.{10} +[0-9,]+ [0-9/]{10} [0-9:]{8} //' || :) = Remove everything before timestamps
    # (awk 'BEGIN { FS=\" -> \" } ; { print \$1 }' || :) = Only show output before ' -> ' in order to remove symlink destinations
    # (grep -v \"^\.$\" || :) = Removes line containing current directory sign '.'



rsync --list-only -rlptgoDE8 /path1 | (grep -E \"^-|^d|^l\" || :) |
    (sed -r 's/^.{10} +[0-9,]+ [0-9/]{10} [0-9:]{8} //' || :) |
    (awk 'BEGIN { FS=\" -> \" } ; { print \$1 }' || :) |
    (grep -v \"^\.$\" || :) | sort > /tmp/path1_list
rsync --list-only -rlptgoDE8 /path2 | (grep -E \"^-|^d|^l\" || :) |
    (sed -r 's/^.{10} +[0-9,]+ [0-9/]{10} [0-9:]{8} //' || :) |
    (awk 'BEGIN { FS=\" -> \" } ; { print \$1 }' || :) |
    (grep -v \"^\.$\" || :) | sort > /tmp/path2_list
comm -23 /tmp/path1_list /tmp/path2_list > final_list
```

Purpose of final_list is to have a list of files which are present in /path1 but not in /path2

[/EDIT]

[EDIT2]

I use rsync to create the file lists because I need to honor rsync exclusion patterns, which I can't with other utilities, hence the whole rsync decoding used for list generation.

The whole project is about statefull file synchronization hosted at https://github.com/deajan/osync

[/EDIT2]

[EDIT3]

michael's answer based on awk works great, except for specific corner cases like:

```
/some/path
/some/path-whatever
/some/path/file
/some/path/subpath/file
/some/otherpath
/some/otherpath/file
```

Overall, I could "dedupe" some of my lists from 48k lines to 50. Not a perfect solution, but does the job so far.

[/EDIT3]

Comment: Is that list generated with `find`?

Comment: Just added the way the lists are generated

Comment: `|| :` makes no sense in case of sed and awk. `\"^\.$\"` just use single quotes everywhere `'"^.$"'`. Use zero separated streams with `-0`. `-rlptgoD` o my, just `-a`... `-E` does nothing, you passed `-p`. Why `-8`? Just use `-0`. Are you just searching for `--delete` rsync option? Could you post sample output from `rsync --list-only`? Did you research if that alll filtering is really needed?

Comment: Your answer is out of context. I can't just replace -rlptgoD with -a since depending on my script options, some options like -lgo will not be used. I just posted the most common example I may use. I am not just searching for the existing --delete option, thanks for trying. Filtering could probably be improved, but that's out of the scope of my question here. -8 parameter handles special unicode characters which would lead to \u1234 like characters in output if not used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that a sorted file of paths would have redundant paths listed after matching substrings, e.g.,

```
/one
/one/two        # dupe, matches /one
/one/two/three  # dupe, matches /one
/two/three
/two/three/four # dupe, matches /two/three
```

Then if you go thru the file, and if the current line contains the substring above it (or, specifically, the shortest substring above it), then just skip those lines:

```
LC_COLLATE=C sort -u file.txt | awk '
    BEGIN { prev="^dummy/" }
    $0 ~ prev { print "# skip: " $0; next }
    $0 !~ prev { print $0; prev="^"$0"/" }'
```

This prefixes lines to skip with `#` so you can see what's omitted, feel free to remove that once you verify this might work.

Notes:

1. I'm ignoring the difference between files and directories, because checking would be messy & a lot slower.
2. Also, `/path/to/file` should *not* cause `/path/to/file2` to be skipped, even though it's a substring as coded, hence I use a regex like `^string/` to assume every entry is a directory to avoid that problem.
3. Technically, having both pattern matches is probably redundant, unless you need to tweak them.
4. Maybe make sure there are no blank lines or other oddities in the input, e.g., `sort input.txt | grep '^/' | awk ...`
5. I added `LC_COLLATE=C` so that `/path/one/` would sort ahead of `/path/one2`, otherwise the original assumption above (sorted substrings indicates subdirs) doesn't hold. (It might not hold in other cases, as well, but then at least there still will be fewer duplicates, but still some duplicates.) I just noticed this problem right as I was posting, and perhaps you'll discover other corner cases, so please do test :-)

Comment: Thanks, that's a nifty solution. I added a corner case to my question, which indeed isn't handled. I guess there's no "easy" way around this since it would require to make much more large comparaisons ?

Comment: perhaps tweaking `sort` options (but a tweak that fixes one problem may cause another), e.g., `sort -d` will sort in "dictionary order", which might be better than changing the collation (e.g., changing `LC_ALL=C sort...` to `sort -d ...`) EDIT: yup, adding `sort -d` breaks sorting `/file` , `/file1` , `/file/two`  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Anyway, that's already more than sufficient ;) Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You need two while loops. The outer while loop reads the base paths. And the inner while loops reads the lines to drop.

```
#! /bin/bash

exec 0< full-list
exec 1> reduced-list

read -r line1
while :; do
  echo "$line1"
  while :; do
    if read -r line2; then
      case $line2 in
        "$line1"/*)
          continue
          ;;
        *)
          line1=$line2
          break
          ;;
      esac
    else
      exit 0
    fi
  done
done
```

The above code assumes that there is at least one line in the full list. If this can not be guaranteed, you have to add an additional `if` statement after the first read.

Comment: Played a bit with that solution, nevertheless I've gone the awk way since it's quicker ;) Thanks

Comment: @OrsirisdeJong You should take that solution, which you are able to maintain.

Comment: I did... already using awk alot in my script. Also, since I try to resolve performance issues, using a compiled C tool like awk outperforms scripts in any case. But as said, thanks for your post... helped me with modelizing the solutions.